# WSO2 Identity Server 5.3.0 - How to get federated authenticator ID

Tags: facebook, authentication, wso2, saml-2.0, wso2-identity-server

With some federated authenticator, let's say Facebook, after redirect back to Service Provider, how can I determine which federated authenticator got invoked?

I see that commonauth is invoked with https://localhost:9443/commonauth?idp=**facebook**&authenticator=**FacebookAuthenticator**&sessionDataKey=faaad26e-8bde-4a14-a865-c40546c4e22f, but what I should do next to forward those variables to my service provider?

Answer (score 2):

Enable "Always send back the authenticated list of identity providers" in "Local & Outbound Authentication Configuration" of the service provider configuration in WSO2 Identity Server.

[image]

When you enable this option, you will receive a parameter called "AuthenticatedIdPs" with the login response. Base64 decode the received value to get list of authenticated idps. Below is a base64 decoded sample value.

```
{
   "typ":"JWT",
   "alg":"none"
}{
   "iss":"wso2",
   "exp":15119303538293000,
   "iat":1511930353829,
   "idps":[
      {
         "idp":"LOCAL",
         "authenticator":"BasicAuthenticator"
      }
   ]
}
```

Refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS530/Configuring+Local+and+Outbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider for more information.

Comment: I already checked that settings. How can I access that JWT token exactly, could you please describe? Currently I have only SAML2 assertion with my user attributes, but not IdP data. Can I add JWT as additional attribute in SAML2 assertion? Should I use completely different approach?

Comment: isn't this list of IDPs sent in the SAML Response?

Comment: @gusto2 No, over here you can see example of SAML2 assertion received by SP: [link](https://jpst.it/184ml)

Comment: This is another parameter in SAML response data sent along with SAMLResponse parameter.

Comment: @MadurangaSiriwardena We have configured Facebook IDP with OpenId Connect configuration and we are able to login but unable to view the claims except for sub. 
User Info response :
{
"sub": "2285108888182031"
}

But in the basic claim configuration of IDP, we have added local claims as email,given_name and family_name (as per oidc scopes present in oidc-scope-config.xml).

What should we do to get the user details?

We are able to get given name, email and family name for linkedin and google with the same setup.

Thanks in advance.